# How do I check if a user exists before saving with Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following form:

```
<h1>New User</h1>
<%= form_for :user, url: users_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :username %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I would like to check to see if the user name exists before saving it.

I have never worked with Ajax, so an example to learn how can I do this would help.

This is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    #       render text: params[:user].inspect
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :description)
  end
end
```

---

UPDATE

I'm trying this on my js file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#user_username').blur(function() { 
        var value = $( this ).val();
        var url = "/users/" + value;        // your url of the function which will return a json or string containing result
    var data = {"username" : value}; // user name to send to server, so that you can compare this in the DB.
    var dataType = "json"; // it depends on the type you sent from the controller. it can be string, json etc..

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function(response){
        alert("pepitonas");
      },
      dataType: dataType
    }); 
    });
});
```

but the application dies. What I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the help of an Ajax request. Include the jQuery script before using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // foo is the id of your form
  $("#foo").submit(function(event){
    var url = ""; // your url of the function which will return a json or string containing result
    var data = {"user_name" : user_name}; // user name to send to server, so that you can compare this in the DB.
    var dataType = "json"; // it depends on the type you sent from the controller. it can be string, json etc..

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function(response){
        // here the code will come to handle response that you sent from your controller function
        // you can return from a string or json from server and then can decode your json right here.
      },
      dataType: dataType
    });    
  });

</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Arbind or the Thin Man, could you check my js code, because is frozen my webapp. Thanks

Comment: @Jean Please check if the url parameter is correct, it must be the one where you are hitting the controller's action. Your url must be accessible. You can verify it by opening firebug tool and going to 'network' tab within it, here you will be able to view the request going to your server. Please make sure that the url on which ajax is hitting is correct. <br> And if that is working fine then you can see "dataType" you are sending from your controller must match the one you specified in the javascript.

Comment: I update my code again, but I getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) to this address http://localhost:3000/users/1 (this address is correct)

Comment: Yes, that means the URL is not correct. Try to hit this url from your browser and see whether you are receiving the request on server(i.e. in your controller). If it works then copy the url from your browser and pass it to the url parameter in the ajax, then it must work.

Comment: Yes, the URL works, but how I have to handle this on my controller?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why you need Ajax for this? All you need is to add validation on your user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :username, uniqueness: true

 end
```

This will reject the user when saving if the username exists.

In your controller change your create action:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And add some way to display an error in your view:

```
  <% if f.object.errors.any? %>
    <p class='error'>
      Cannot save object due to following errors:
      <ul>
        <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |error|%>
          <li><%= error %></li> 
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :username %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </p>
```

Comment: Thanks BoirSatse, I need to check if the user exist like twitter, and let continue the user creation if the username is available